# Sum and Average from user input

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with creating a program to compute the average of some test scores. I am receiving an error along the lines of "expected type 'int', got 'none' instead". I understand what this means, but I don't know why it's happening.

Here is my code:

```
#Get information from user, declare and define variables
name = input("Please enter your name")
howManyTests = int(input('How many test scores are you entering?'))
#For loop to calculate test grade average
for n in range(howManyTests):
    lst = []
    grades = float(input('Enter test grade: '))
    sum_grades = lst.append(grades)
testavg = sum_grades/howManyTests
print('Hi ',name,' your average of ',howManyTests, ' tests is :', testavg)
```

Comment: What do you think `append` returns, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `lst.append(grades)` returns `None`, because it modifies the `lst` list in-place. Don't assign its return value to a variable.
2. You're reassigning the `lst` variable to an empty list at the beginning of every iteration of the `for` loop -- as a result, it will contain only one element after you've exited the loop.

Here is a code snippet that fixes both of these issues:

```py
#Get information from user, declare and define variables
name = input("Please enter your name")
howManyTests = int(input('How many test scores are you entering?'))
#For loop to calculate test grade average
lst = []
for n in range(howManyTests):
    grades = float(input('Enter test grade: '))
    lst.append(grades)
testavg = sum(lst)/howManyTests
print('Hi ',name,' your average of ',howManyTests, ' tests is :', testavg)
```

Comment: This was a lot of help, thank you so much!